# Relation Between the Hessian Matrix at the max of loglikelihood and the Hessian matrix at the minimum of -loglikelihood

Tags: likelihood, hessian

I would like to now what is the relation between the Hessian Matrix calculated at the maximum point of the log(likelihood) function, $H_{f}$ and the Hessian Matrix calculated at the minimum point of the -log(likelihood) function, $H_{-f}$.

The first should be definite negative and the second should be definite positive. But, is it possible to calculate the first hessian matrix from the second one?

It should be $H_{f}=-H_{-f}$, but I am not sure. Is there any proof of it?
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Let $\ell(\theta)$, for $\theta\in\Theta$, be the log-likelihood function. Then the maximum likelihood estimate is defined as

$$\hat\theta = \text{arg}\,\underset{\theta\in\Theta}{\min}-\ell(\theta)\\
\,\, = \text{arg}\, \underset{\theta\in\Theta}{\max}\ell(\theta)$$

Now, by the properties of the differentiation operator

$$\frac{d^2-\ell(\theta)}{d\theta d\theta^T} = -\frac{d^2\ell(\theta)}{d\theta d\theta^T},
$$

which holds for any $\theta$. In particular, for $\hat\theta$ we have that

$$
\frac{d^2-\ell(\theta)}{d\theta d\theta^T}|_{\theta=\hat\theta} = -\frac{d^2\ell(\theta)}{d\theta d\theta^T}\vert_{\theta=\hat\theta}.
$$